# Nothing starts after login, only background is shown (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: unity, gnome, login

(Don't mark as duplicate, nothing helps from other answers!)

After Ubuntu 14.04 log in screen, whether I log into Gnome or Unity, only desktop background shows up. Nothing starts. I can't even run terminal through ctrl + alt + t.

I can however start the console through ctrl + alt + 1.

From there, I tried to start unity, and it works only partially. The icons and sidebar show up when I switch back to desktop from console, but it's very slow, buggy and unusable.

This is the log from running unity from console (I run it with "sudo unity", then I switch to desktop and it starts, but it's buggy, so I stop it back in console):

```
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:55 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.Shell' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
ERROR 2014-09-23 13:30:55 unity.debug.interface DebugDBusInterface.cpp:216 Unable to load entry point in libxpathselect: libxpathselect.so.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:55 unity <unknown>:0 Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-GuO8uIKHKy: Connection refused
ERROR 2014-09-23 13:30:56 unityo (appinfo2) <unknown>:0 g_file_monitor_set_rate_limit: assertion 'G_IS_FILE_MONITOR (monitor)' failed
ERROR 2014-09-23 13:30:56 unity.launcher.icon.trash TrashLauncherIcon.cpp:66 Could not create file monitor for trash uri: Operation not supported
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:56 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:56 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Dash' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:56 unityn_param_values == 4 <unknown>:0 The owner of /home/stanny/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:56 nux.inputmethod.ibus InputMethodIBus.cpp:63 Impossible to connect to connect to ibus
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:56 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
ERROR 2014-09-23 13:30:56 unityo (appinfo2) <unknown>:0 g_dbus_proxy_new_for_bus: assertion 'g_variant_is_object_path (object_path)' failed
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:56 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Session' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:56 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:57 unityinit <unknown>:0 failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=778447ddcfac03e3118fe35c53c14244 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process killed by signal 43
```

Then thousands of these:

```
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:57 unityinit <unknown>:0 failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=778447ddcfac03e3118fe35c53c14244 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process killed by signal 43
```

Then this:

```
ERROR 2014-09-23 13:30:57 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'org.gnome.Shell'
ERROR 2014-09-23 13:30:57 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'com.canonical.Unity'
```

Then a lot of these, again:

```
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:57 unityinit <unknown>:0 failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=778447ddcfac03e3118fe35c53c14244 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process killed by signal 43
```

Then this:

```
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:57 unity.glib.dbus.proxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:417 Calling method "CanShutdown" on object path: "/org/gnome/SessionManager" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
WARN  2014-09-23 13:30:57 unityinit <unknown>:0 failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=778447ddcfac03e3118fe35c53c14244 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process killed by signal 43
ERROR 2014-09-23 13:30:57 unity.session.gnome GnomeSessionManager.cpp:357 Gnome Session call failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Then the "failed to commit changes" warnings continue for the entirety of ~30MB logfile. I eventually have to stop it from console.

What I've tried so far:

1. Reinstalling ubuntu-desktop.
2. Reinstalling gnome.
3. As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), I've tried enabling unity plugin in ccsm, but it doesn't help either. Neither does the "sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/" from another answer.
4. Installing fluxbox.

When I'm installing ubuntu-destkop and gnome, and their dependencies, I get this error:

```
Unable to autolaunch a dbus daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

(I wrote that down, so I'm not sure if it's 100% correct.)

From these, only installing fluxbox works.

I'm writing this logged in fluxbox and it works without any problems. However, when I choose Gnome or Ubuntu from the log in screen, the same problem of nothing starting up persists.

Comment: I probably don't know the answer, but I can come up with questions. What display card do you have?  There may be a parameter you can enter at boot time for problem cards; I personally never had problems in that area except a very old laptop that I never pursued.

Comment: @MartyFried I never had this problem either. I've been running Ubuntu smoothly for a month or two now. I have no idea what I did, if I did anything at all, to cause this. My card is  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV516/M64-S [Mobility Radeon X2300]. I wonder if I could solve this by reinstalling the drivers, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: But you said you reinstalled everything, so the drivers also get reinstalled.  Does the live system on the CD or USB work?  If so, something doesn't fit.

Comment: @MartyFried I reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and gnome, I don't know if that reinstalls the drivers, too. I'll try the Live CD.

Comment: Normally, a reinstall also reformats the partition, although it *is* optional.  Did you reformat first?  If so, it had to reinstall everything.

Comment: @MartyFried You misunderstood, I didn't reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. I reinstalled ubuntu-desktop from the console: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-desktop I'm trying to avoid reinstalling Ubuntu entirely, because I don't have a CD burner, which would mean I'd have to reinstall Ubuntu 12.xx, the only Linux CD I have with me, over 14.xx.

Comment: @MartyFried I now think that the problem is that none of the .desktop startup files from /etc/xdg/autostart are being run after logging in. How would I solve this?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. If you are correct about the .desktop files, I'm not sure what starts them.  What happens if you enter this in a virtual console: `echo $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`? I don't run unity or gnome shell, but I get `/etc/xdg/xdg-gnome-fallback-compiz:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg`. These are the directories for autostart desktop files. I hope someone else will come in that might know more.

Comment: @MartyFried `echo $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` returns nothing, just an empty, black line.

Comment: That may be your problem; I haven't found where that is set. There is some info [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), but I don't know how much help it will be.  You can try searching for that term, though, and maybe get a clue.

Comment: @MartyFried Well I searched and searched, but I couldn't find exactly where you're supposed to set `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`  to `/etc/xdg/xdg-gnome:/etc/xdg` (the page you linked to suggests setting it only to `/etc/xdg`, but this is what I get when I echo it in fresh install). I tried setting it in `user-dirs.dirs` in `~/.config` and `/etc/xdg/autostart/` but neither helped. I'm pretty sure that was the problem. I reinstalled Ubuntu, and everything works great now. Thanks for your help, anyway!